# Is there any plugin available for Wi-Fi Direct in cordova?

Tags: android, sockets, cordova, wifi, phonegap

I have to create an app in Cordova that connects via Wi-Fi Direct to an Android app. Is there any way to do it? Is there a plugin that allows me to use this technology in Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is one [listed on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wifi-direct), but I've no experience with it.

If you're just trying to share files / receive files, I'd take a look at Eddy Verbruggen's [social sharing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing) and [custom URL scheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme) plugins, respectively. These plugins are cross-platform.